# C# Project Reference Warning Type confilict

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, xunit, project-reference

I have a main asp.net core project which is called "API" and inside of it I have another project called "API.Tests" for xunit tests. So when I'm referencing main project (`<ProjectReference Include="..\API.csproj" />`), to get access to main's project classes, I'm also referencing everything that's inside of a "API.Tests" project since it's inside of a main project. That's why this warning appears when I'm trying to inherit one class from another in test project:[image: warning]

This is `API.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This is `API.Tests.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2"></PackageReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\API.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Please help, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: have you tried to alias the imports (e.g. `using myAPI = API.Controller` then use it in the inheritance as `AccountControllerDependencyProvider : myAPI.DependencyProvider`?

Comment: Good idea, but sadly it will not help, because I will still have 2 same classes, which will conflict with each other. I could move all the classes from which I want to inherit to the main project, but it will be a mess later. There's got to be a better solution.

Comment: there is no permanent fix if you have two accessible classes that share the same name. aliasing is a bandaid to help the compiler navigate the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can and should do is put the production code in a sub-project as well and reference that sub-project from API.Tests instead of the main project.

i.e.

```
API
   \API.Application
   \API.Tests
```

with API.Tests referencing API.Application.